# SQL management of hierarchy

Tags: sql

We have inherited the support of an application that manages a hierarchical reporting structure. 
The table structure is:

**id_from, id_to, active, value..** so in essence a tree of four tiers.

An example being:

```
A B C D -> item q
A B C E -> item r
A B C F -> item s
A B G H -> item t
```

In the table we hold

```
id_from, Id_to, active, Value
     A    B       Y      .
     B    C       Y      .
     C    D       Y      item q
     C    E       Y      item r
     C    F       Y      item s
     B    G       Y      .
     G    H       Y      item t
```

So we are only holding each unique pairing once.
The problem being we need to run many changes programmatically against the structure.
One example being:

```
A B C D -> item q
```

becomes:

```
A T C D -> item q
```

So the data set becomes:

```
A T C D -> item q
A B C E -> item r
A B C F -> item s
A B G H -> item t
```

Thus the table would be

```
id_from, Id_to, active, Value
A    T   Y
T    C   Y
A    B   Y
B    C   Y
C    D   Y item q
C    E   Y item r
C    F   Y item s
B    G   Y 
G    H   Y item t
```

but as per this example this isn't correct as the tree would still produce a link of A B C D as well as A T C D

In fact we would need to change the other C values to something else.

```
id_from, Id_to, active, Value
A    T   Y
T    C   Y
A    B   Y
B    Cx  Y 
C    D   Y item q
Cx   E   Y item r
Cx   F   Y item s
B    G   Y 
G    H   Y item t
```

This is only one example of many problems we see - but I wonder if this structure is a recognised model?
And therefore is there a link that can give us general algorithms for managing the structure.

Comment: I understand you have a table, let's say Report (Id, Value1, Value2, ...) and another Relations (FromDataId, ToDataId). Why would your Relation have a Value column?

Comment: your example is a little bit confusing! i dont think that this is a recognised model! it looks a little bit like a nested set structure.

Comment: Hi 'Why would your Relation have a Value column...' This is a very much simplified model of the actual structure - so it would be hard to explain the full details.. All be it we can't change it, we just need to understand how to manage it.

Comment: hi, is a redesign an option? i understand that your tree structure is _exactly_ 4 tiers deep so dump the tree structure, drop columns id_from, id_to, add columns id_1-id_4 representing the former tree path and make them a composite key. do i miss something ?

Answer (score 1):

Try: [Recursive Queries Using Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx)!

One of the great gems of SQL Server and available since SQL Server 2005. This is my goto for anything involving a hierarchy in SQL Server.

The structure of a CTE query goes something like this:

```
With <define derived table>
<do ground level hierarchy query>
join 
<all child elements>;

use results and join with other tables, if needed
```